# como validar que no se repita en la base de datos el correo electronico al subir un archivo MultipartFile file (csv) en spring boot

Tags: java, api, objeto

estoy subiendo el archivo cvs y lo guardo en la base de datos pero si ya existe ese campo cuando lo vuelvo a subir el cvs me los vuelve a registrar.
como puedo validar que si ese correo electronico ya esta registrado en la base no suba el que esta en el archivo csv.

```
  @PostMapping("/upload")
            public ResponseEntity<Object> uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
                ResponseEntity<Object> responseEntity = null;
                CustomResponse customResponse = new CustomResponse();
                String message = "";
                try {
                    if (CSVHelper.hasCSVFormat(file)) {
                        fileService.save(file);
                        customResponse.setHttpCode(HttpStatus.CREATED);
                        customResponse.setCode(201);
                        customResponse.setMensaje("Uploaded the file successfully");
        
                        customResponse.setData(CSVHelper.csvToE(file.getInputStream()));
                        responseEntity = ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(customResponse);
                    }
        
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    message = "Could not upload the file: " + file.getOriginalFilename() + "!";
                    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.EXPECTATION_FAILED).body(new ResponseMessage(message));
                }
        
                return responseEntity;
            }
```

Comment: Agregale detalles a tu pregunta. ¿A cuál correo electrónico te referís? ¿Qué es ´fileService´?

Comment: El correo electrónico al que te refieres, está indicado dentro del objeto MultipartFile?